# Adding Alt Attributes Automatically when Uploading Images to Media Library

Tags: media-library

I have lots of images that has to be uploaded via media library. I want to know, is it possible to add file name to `alt` attribute field automatically when I am uploading them? At the moment I have to open each image and add the `alt` attribute manually.

Answer (score 1):

A viable solution I [found](https://gist.github.com/svil4ok/1991931) was adding the *post title* to images missing the `ALT` attribute.

Add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
function add_alt_tags($content)
{
        global $post;
        preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $content, $images);
        if(!is_null($images))
        {
                foreach($images[1] as $index => $value)
                {
                        if(!preg_match('/alt=/', $value))
                        {
                                $new_img = str_replace('<img', '<img alt="'.$post->post_title.'"', $images[0][$index]);
                                $content = str_replace($images[0][$index], $new_img, $content);
                        }
                }
        }
        return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_alt_tags', 99999);
```

Alternatively, if you want to replace the attribute with the file name, you could look into using the [get_attached_file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) function for the `$new_img` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late to the party, but I couldn't let this one pass because I wrote a plugin just for this: [Auto Image Attributes From Filename With Bulk Updater](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-image-attributes-from-filename-with-bulk-updater/)

As the name suggests, there is a bulk updater as well, so you can update existing images as well.